# finding a soild from five planes

Tags: analytic-geometry

Given five planes:

$\pi_1=2x+5y+z-2=0$

$\pi_2=x+y-z-1=0$

$\pi_3=x+4y+2z-4=0$

$\pi_4=3x-y+4z-3=0$

$\pi_5=-6x+2y-8z+k=0$.

How can i find the solid shape that is formed by those planes?

I tried to draw but it's too complex.

I can see that for a solid to be exists $k\neq6$.

Any help?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe use software...

Comment: so drawing is the only "easy" way?

Comment: Five planes in general position can determine 26 regions of space, of which several will be bounded.  Which of these is your solid?  It's not an easy problem.  I suggest replacing each equation with an inequality.  There are $2^{5}=32$ choices, each of which will lead to one of the regions.  Plot them all, and see which solid(s) are the ones you want.

Comment: i think i got a prism with triangle as a base, by finding the lines from $\pi_1,\pi_3$ and from $\pi_2,\pi_3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How $\pi_2$ , $\pi_3$ are independents planes and $\pi_1$ in linear combination of $\pi_2$ and $\pi_3$ but the except to independent term so is a prisma triagular infinity.

How the plane $\pi_4$ , $\pi_5$ and $k\neq{6}$ are parallel planes then is a triangular prism bounded for this planes.

Comment: yes that's what i wrote in the comment but just by drawing which was hard.

Comment: solve the systems $\pi_1$, $\pi_2$ and $\pi_1$, $\pi_3$.

Comment: why $\pi_1$ is linear combination of $\pi_2,\pi_3$? as i see it $\pi_2+\pi_3 \neq \pi_1$

Comment: the vector normal of $\pi_1$ is combination linear of normal vectors of $\pi_2$ and $\pi_3$.

Comment: that's true, thanks.